# Monte Carlo Summary Statistics

Tags: descriptive-statistics, monte-carlo

Suppose I am performing MC analysis of a method that produces statistical results.  To be precise, consider an MC study of linear regression where we are performing regression on a single data set that is slightly perturbed with white noise.   Now, each MC run ($k=1, \dots, N$) is used to calculate errors $\varepsilon(k)$, and a covariance matrix $P(k)$.  Under the hypothesis that the errors are Gaussian, we may compute a chi-squared statistic by way of $\zeta(k) = \varepsilon(k)^T P^{-1}(k) \varepsilon(k)$.

Now suppose I have done hundreds of runs, $N >> 1$, and want to know what the statistical results are of jiggling my data set on the linear regression estimates.  I have hundreds of chi-squared tests, hundreds of errors, and hundreds of covariances.  Is there a method for a summary statistic for these quantities?  There's the idea of simply taking the mean, but is it proper to take the mean of the results of statistical tests and perform something of a meta-statistical test?  How do I say, with some confidence level, that linear regression is robust to small noises in the sample?

Edit: Perhaps to clarify, we can also consider a simple Kalman filter.  This produces a state estimate and a covariance.  I may run my Kalman filer through 1000 MC runs, each run producing a collection of states and covariance matrices.  At each time for each run, I can compute a chi-squared statistical test.  Is there some kind of summary statistic I may use to reduce the 1000 chi-square scores at each time step to a single combined chi-squared score that summarizes the results across all 1000 runs?

Comment: Not sure from your question if this is the kind of thing you're seeking, but if you're interested in whether the chi-square statistic has close to a chi-square distribution, you can apply the probability integral transform and examine how close the ecdf of that is to the line from (0,0) to (1,1) (e.g. via a plot of it, or via some goodness of fit statistic)

Comment: It sounds as if you might not be familiar with the literature on meta-analysis and that you would benefit from readings there.  Frederick Wolf put together a nice introductory book.

Comment: @rolando2 thank you for the reference.  I am not familiar with meta-analysis and that sounds like precisely what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, thanks for the reply.  I know the different forms of the chi-squared test.  The root of my question is that my LS estimator comes with a mean and covariance as part of the algorithm.  How to do I perform analysis on these statistical values (mean and covariance) if I have them from MC runs?  As rolando2 said, it sounds like meta-analysis is what I need.  Eg what can I say about 1000 covariance matrices that came out of MC studies of linear regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same rules apply as for choosing summary statistics for any other kind of data. You can use mean, standard deviation, standard error, quantiles, mode etc. depending on what kind of information about the data you want to learn. Additionally, it is worth plotting the data (histograms, density plots, scatter plots), and calculate multivariate statistical summaries (e.g. correlation).

Comment: thank you for the reply.  Would this constitute simple meta-statistics?  I don't need to consider individual covariances and chi-squared scores to weight each run correctly?  Is this because each run is a realization of the exact same scenario and so can be treated like any other random collection?

Comment: @Matt you use Monte Carlo to take draws from a distribution of some random variable. Statistics calculated on those values are in fact functions of random variable, and as so, random variables itself. So you are dealing with just another kind of random variables and you need same kind of statistical summaries.